What happens to current in a wire with a chunk taken out of it?
What happens to current when a the cross sectional area of a wire changes?
Here is what I'm visualizing:

A material with conductivity $\sigma$ is formed into a square wire with cross sectional area $A$.
Take a sample that is $\ell = 10$ cm long, then apply a small test voltage $V_t$ along the length of the wire.
Cut a piece out of the wire. The piece is 1 mm long, and reduces the cross sectional area to $A/2$ for that 1 mm. Apply the same test voltage $V_t$.

Before the defect is introduced, everything is calculated as follows:
$$E = V_t/\ell$$
$$J = \sigma E$$
$$ I = J A$$
$$ R = \ell/\sigma A $$
After the defect is introduced, I'm not sure how to perform the calculation. Here's what I have:

According to the equations above, the electric field $E=V/\ell$ remains the same along the length of the wire, therefore $J=\sigma E$ will remain constant, and the current $I = JA$ will decrease during the defect. (This seems wrong to me; $I$ should be constant along the length of the wire)
The test current $I$ will remain constant, so the current density $J=I/A$ will double for the duration of the the defect. This means the the electric field and the voltage will increase in the region of the defect. (But $E=V_t/\ell$ is constant, so this is inconsistent)
The resistance of the system will change with the introduction of the defect, so recalculate $R$, use that to find $I = V_t/R$, and calculate $J$ and $E$ based on changes in area. (But why doesn't the approach above work?)

Please help me understand this simple system!

Think of the wire as a whole bunch of small resistors in series. If all resistors are the same, the wire is of constant cross section all the way. If the cross section varies, the resistance of that section changes (up or down depending).

@JonCuster Yes! I agree. So how to properly do the calculation?

Calculate the equivalent resistance of the wire. Everything else follows from that.

Consider the system as two resistors (with lengths $dl$=1mm and $l-dl$=9.9cm) in series - the second resistors cross section is changed from $A$ to $\lambda A$ (with $0<\lambda\le1$)
\begin{align}
R_\text{before} &= R_1+R_2=\rho\frac{l-dl}{A}+\rho\frac{dl}{A}=\rho\frac{l}{A}\\
R_\text{after} &= R_1+\tilde{R_2}=\rho\frac{l-dl}{A}+\rho\frac{dl}{\lambda A}=\rho\frac{(l-dl)+dl/\lambda}{A}
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
I_\text{before}&=\frac{V}{R_\text{before}}=\frac{VA}{\rho l}\\
I_\text{after}&=\frac{V}{R_{after}}=\frac{VA}{\rho[(l-dl)+dl/\lambda]}=\frac{VA}{\rho l\left[\left(1-\frac{dl}{l}\right)+\frac{1}{\lambda}\frac{dl}{l}\right]}
\end{align}



... $J=\sigma E$ will remain constant, and the current $I = JA$ will decrease during the defect. (This seems wrong to me; $I$ should be constant along the length of the wire)


You are right to be concerned about this step. $I$ is constant along the length of the wire.
That means $E$ and $J$ are not constant along the length of the wire.


The test current $I$ will remain constant, so the current density $J=I/A$ will double for the duration of the the defect.


Yes, this is the correct way to set up your solution.

But $E=V_t/\ell$ is constant, so this is inconsistent

There is no rule that says $E=V_t/\ell$ is constant unless the wire has a constant cross section and homogeneous material. And the rule for the constant cross section and homogeneous case is derived from the fact that the current is constant.
